# Responsive video's

Tags: html, css

quick question:

I'm using a couple videos, and I want them to be 100% of the screen at every viewport, without stretching the video. I put width & height on 100%, and I understand that that won't work, because video's have fixed resolutions. But how can I make the video full screen on desktop/tablet/mobile? I searched for a video alternative to the picture tag with source tag: srcset, sizes etc; but that doesn't support video tags.

Any ideas?

Comment: you should put out your code and your tries

Comment: You can try object-fit: cover; CSS property. Check this example https://jsfiddle.net/kawal/sbuomtp2/5/